# What’s the issue with the controller code below? How would you fix it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  def users_comments
    posts = Post.all
    comments = posts.map(&:comments).flatten
    @user_comments = comments.select do |comment|
      comment.author.username == params[:username]
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: what error do you get ? Please elaborate your questionns with error and logs

Comment: 1. You should not be using .all, it will bring up all the records in memory, which will increase the response time

2. You should be using eager loading. Read about it [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html)

Answer (score 1):

This will produce so much queries. This problem is called n+1 (see here: https://www.sitepoint.com/silver-bullet-n1-problem/).

I suggest using something like this code:

```
@user_comments = Comment.where(author: { username: params[:username] })
```

I think you don't need the Posts am I right?

Answer (score 0):

Its  just a normal general question anyone can google it as it requires the smallest change to the existing code and makes no assumptions regarding the reverse association of Comment to Post.
Read Few More Interesting facts about [Ruby on Rails Development](http://www.railscarma.com/blog) from Here

Answer (score -1):

This tells ActiveRecord to retrieve the corresponding Comment and Author records from the database immediately after the initial request for all Posts, thereby reducing the number of database requests to just three.